# What is NSMouseInRect in Xamarin

Tags: c#, objective-c, macos, xamarin.ios

What is the equivalent method for this following Objective-C method in C#/Xamarin?

```
NSMouseInRect(location, buttonRect, [controlView isFlipped])
```

Comment: Does [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/appkit.nsview.ismouseinrect?view=xamarin-mac-sdk-14#AppKit_NSView_IsMouseInRect_CoreGraphics_CGPoint_CoreGraphics_CGRect_) help?

Comment: @Sweeper: a bit different but it worked out. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't find `NSMouseInRect` in the Xamarin.Mac framework either, but...

You can use the [`NSView.IsMouseInRect`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/appkit.nsview.ismouseinrect?view=xamarin-mac-sdk-14#AppKit_NSView_IsMouseInRect_CoreGraphics_CGPoint_CoreGraphics_CGRect_) method:

```
controlView.IsMouseInRect(location, buttonRect)
```

This method handles the `isFlipped` property automatically!